# Why doesn't ToUpper() return "*" when applied to "8"?

Tags: c#

```
string s = "h";
s = s.ToUpper();
```

returns `"H"`.

```
string s = "8";
s = s.ToUpper();
```

returns `"8"`

Should this not return `"*"`?

Comment: It's **upper case** letters, not whatever is up on top of your letter in your keyboard layout..

Comment: I love the up-vote on this (which wasn't mine).  It's an amazingly silly question, but it's also a clear and well-presented question.  Kudos on a rare mix of the two!

Comment: @David: Not mine either but I think it's purely for the silliness.

Comment: I wonder if some of the upvoters read "doesn't" as "does", because that how I read it originally, and that seemed unexpected.

Comment: It would be helpful to note that typewriters used to do this - that is, hitting "shift" and "8" would result in "*".

Comment: I should hope it’s uppercase for *more* than merely letters, but for any Unicode code point that has a defined uppercase mapping. Not all cased code points are letters, you know. For example `unichars -gas '\PL' '\P{Upper}' 'uc =~ /\p{Upper}/'` using [the unichars script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) identifies lots of non-letters that are non-uppers who neverlesss *do have an uppercase mapping.* Start with the odd U+345 ◌ͅ   which is a `\p{Mn}`; then there are Roman numbers of type `\p{Nl}` like `ⅵ`; finaly you’ve code points like `ⓣ ` which are `\p{So}`.

Comment: A coworker and I once debated at length about whether `8` is uppercase or lowercase. (this was related to a discussion about coding standards.)

Comment: Why does this have 18 upvotes? :S

Comment: May be for its innocence behind the question..  The OP is really a new kid..

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. `ToUpper()` doesn't mean `WithShiftKeyOnAnInternationalASCIIKeyboard()`. There isn't an uppercase 8, as 8 is a *number*, not a *letter*.

Of course, this is a *gross* over-simplification (being a *number* alone doesn't automatically make a certain *character* in a character set caseless), but it's likely what you're asking for anyway so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I've always wanted that function

Comment: my keyboard has a ( above the 8 :P

Comment: @BlackBear: Further proving what Oded says :)

Comment: Does it only work with letters, or does is work with all cased code points?

Comment: You'd think there aren't uppercase and lowercase numbers. But [you would be wrong](http://goo.gl/PUiig) (page 2)

Comment: I know, it's already been mentioned multiple times. I'd delete my answer if I could because of the amount of wrong in it, or shall I get a mod to do so?

Comment: @Bolt Na... 8 still doesn't have an uppercase mapping.

Comment: +1 for this function WithShiftKeyOnAnInternationalASCIIKeyboard()

Answer (score 28):

Because there is no upper case `8`.

Just because the specific keyboard you are using has a `*` on the same key as the `8`, doesn't mean that all keyboards do. Some languages do not have upper case letter - what should `ToUpper` return for those?

[`String.ToUpper()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed.aspx):

> This method uses the casing rules of the current culture to convert each character in the current instance to its uppercase equivalent. If a character does not have an uppercase equivalent, it is included unchanged in the returned string.

Comment: That text says character, not letter.  So does `"ⅳ".ToUpper()` properly return "Ⅳ" as it is supposed to, etc?

Comment: @tchrist - It does. I tested this on LinqPad. Got `Ⅳ`.

Answer (score 6):

The real answer is because the TextInfo associated with the CultureInfo for en-US does not define "*" as the uppercase of "8".

It may be possible to extend that TextInfo, override toUpper(), and have it work like you wish.

Answer (score 1):

1. Numbers don't have uppercases.
2. if you would use the function `ToUpper()` to following Text:
   "there are 8 buildings"
   What result would you like to have?
   "THERE ARE 8 BUILDINGS" or "THERE ARE * BUILDINGS"
3. the Keyboardlayout is localized e.g. on german keyboards there is a **(** at the **8** key

Answer (score -1):

Just because you press shift 8 to get a * doesnt make it an uppercase value, it only applies for a-z characters.

Comment: It certainly applies to more than just a-z.  For instance: `Debug.WriteLine("ελληνικά".ToUpper());` output's "ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΆ".  It converts to upper case based on the rules of the current culture settings.